# Edit a list in a given position?

Tags: list, haskell

And it goes like this.
Someone have a chain of restaurants. each restaurant is a 3-tuple with a “restaurant name”, an number of tables and a 3-tuple list with the menu (price, "recipe name" , "special ingredient") :

```
("restaurant name", number of tables, [(price, "recipe name" , "special ingredient")])
```

So, I got something like:

```
chainRestaurants = [("Food and friends",20,[(2.5,"Steak","lemon"),(3.5,"Vegetarian Meals","tomato"),(4.0,"Italian Beef","banana")]),("All in",10,[(2.5,"Stracotto","Garlic"),(3.0,"Roast Beef","Butter"),(3.3,"Veal Chops","Pepper")]),("Orange",25,[(4.5,"Turkey","Mustard"),(5.1,"Chicken","egg"),(6.0,"Chicken Salad","fruit")])]
```

Part of my assignment (the part where I’m stuck in) is: pick the restaurantlist and add, replace, change the order, edit the menus, the restaurants and the restaurant chain list.

So, the Question: make a function that allows to edit a 3-tuple (a recipe) from a menu, given the restaurant name position, the menu position and the new recipe.

example: editRecipe 1 2 (2222,"SSSSSS","llllll")

output:

```
[("Food and friends",20,[(2.5,"Steak","lemon"),(2222,"SSSSSS","llllll"),(4.0,"Italian Beef","banana")]),("All in",10,[(2.5,"Stracotto","Garlic"),(3.0,"Roast Beef","Butter"),(3.3,"Veal Chops","Pepper")]),("Orange",25,[(4.5,"Turkey","Mustard"),(5.1,"Chicken","egg"),(6.0,"Chicken Salad","fruit")])]
```

I've already solve this problem, but never with a 3-tuple as an argument... and I need it! :/

There's my code:

```
chainRestaurants = [("Food and friends",20,[(2.5,"Steak","lemon"),(3.5,"Vegetarian Meals","tomato"),(4.0,"Italian Beef","banana")]),("All in",10,[(2.5,"Stracotto","Garlic"),(3.0,"Roast Beef","Butter"),(3.3,"Veal Chops","Pepper")]),("Orange",25,[(4.5,"Turkey","Mustard"),(5.1,"Chicken","egg"),(6.0,"Chicken Salad","fruit")])]

menu1 = [(2.5,"Steak","lemon"),(3.5,"Vegetarian Meals","tomato"),(4.0,"Italian Beef","banana")]
restaurant1 = ("Food and friends",20,menu1)

menu2 = [(2.5,"Stracotto","Garlic"),(3.0,"Roast Beef","Butter"),(3.3,"Veal Chops","Pepper")]
restaurant2 = ("All in",10,menu2)

menu3 = [(4.5,"Turkey","Mustard"),(5.1,"Chicken","egg"),(6.0,"Chicken Salad","fruit")]
restaurant3 = ("Orange",25,menu3)

chainRestaurants1 = [restaurant1] ++ [restaurant2] ++ [restaurant3]


editRecipe restaurantposition menuposition newrecipe | menuposition == 0 = error "No such thing" 
                                                 | restaurantposition == 1 &&   menuposition > length menu1 = error "No such thing" 
                                                 | restaurantposition == 2 && menuposition > length menu2 = error "No such thing" 
                                                 | restaurantposition == 3 && menuposition > length menu3 = error "No such thing" 

editRecipe restaurantposition menuposition newrecipe = case restaurantposition of 1 -> [("Food and friends",20, take (menuposition-1) menu1 ++ newrecipe ++ drop (menuposition) menu1)] ++ [restaurant2] ++ [restaurant3]
                                                                                2 -> [restaurant1] ++ [("Food and friends",20, take (menuposition-1) menu2 ++ newrecipe ++ drop (menuposition) menu2)] ++ [restaurant3]
                                                                                3 -> [restaurant1] ++ [restaurant2] ++ [("Orange",25, take (menuposition-1) menu3 ++ newrecipe ++ drop (menuposition) menu3)]
                                                                                otherwise -> error "No such thing"
```

But this code need a list (newrecipe) as argument, but I need a 3-tuple. :/

```
ex: editRecipe 1 2 [(5.1,"xxxxxxxxx","ccccccccccc")]
```

and I need:

```
editRecipe 1 2 (5.1,"xxxxxxxxx","ccccccccccc")
```

But with my code, I must insert a list whit a tuple as argument. The question is: is it possible to insert only a tuple as argument and not a list?

Comment: It doesn't matter if that argument is a 3-tuple or any other kind of value... It should work the same way as where you solved this problem before.

Comment: The SO community responds much better if you provide your code that failed, even if it doesn't compile.  Allowing us to give advice and point out easier methods.

Comment: This question is vague. What exactly do you want your function(s) to do?

Comment: If you have tuple `t` you can make list from it via `[t]` or `return t`.

Comment: Well @Matvey , I was almost sure that I've already try that (I've tryed almost everything I now) ... but... It works! so simple :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is vague, but perhaps this will help.

Actually, you cannot *edit* tuples, list, etc. Instead you should *construct* new tuple, list, etc. from old. For example, you want to insert some `Int` in `[Int]` at position `n`:

```
insert :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
insert n x xs = before ++ [x] ++ after
  where
    (before, after) = splitAt n xs
```

Then:

```
> insert 5 100 [1..10]
[1,2,3,4,5,100,6,7,8,9,10]
```